# Missing site assets when no local\Users permission on the folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, umbraco

I'm working on the Umbraco site (asp.net MVC) hosted on local Windows Server 2016+IIS10.
During regular template modification, I have experienced strange behavior - the site lost all of the assets hosted from local files. All the requests to cases or images were redirected to the login page. A few people reported similar behavior, commonly resolving it by permission checking. So did I - ensured that my pool user has granted full access to the folder and all its descendants. It was, so I removed it and applied it once again. Still no luck. I have copied the website files and created another web app in IIS - this one worked without any glitch.
Later, my co-worker found that the application folder is missing access permission for the local machine "Users" group. When we added it - the site is served without any issues.
The webserver is part of the corporate domain (AD) and the app pool user is a "service user".

Is it normal that it needs both - pool user and local "Users" permission?

Why is so?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. When the static file and the application are in same machine, the application needs higher permissions to read the static file.

When the application runs in IIS, it will use the identity of the application pool to read static files, and the default identity of the application pool is ApplicationPoolIdentity, with the lowest permissions.

The test in visual studio does not have this problem because IIS express runs the application with the same permissions as the administrator.